# Does trample ability have any effect during a fight between two creatures out of combat?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does trample ability have any effect during a fight between two creatures out of combat?

I'll explain better.
**When** any card or effect allows **two creatures to fight each other** - *for example, when a [Territorial Allosaurus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerritorial%20Allosaurus%5d) is summoned by paying its kicker cost* -  it is good to clarify how the various creatures' abilities still have an effect.

The question is this:
-"**Does trample ability have any effect during or after a fight between two creatures out of combat?"**.
I give an example.
If two creatures are invited to fight each other, *let's say a [War Mammoth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWar%20Mammoth%5d) and a [Scryb Sprites](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bScryb%20Sprites%5d)*, after the fight ended normally with the Mammoth's victory, the fact that there are two points left that the Mammoth could deal with the trample ability, does it have any relevance in a case like this?
That is,following the same example: **does the Mammoth's controller have the chance of dealing them to the opponent?**

Comment: Wait, are you really stating, that first strike is taken into account when two creatures fight? Have you even read up on the ruling on fight?!

Comment: Oh! Really? This puzzles me ... I was absolutely sure that the first strike ability applied to the fight ...! So I' m going to correct the question right now, at least on this point. Thank you,Erik.

Comment: But now - afer the editing - the two linked questions don't seem similar to me anymore. Here we talk about trample ability: so I invite Hackworth to reread this question, and to see if it is still a duplicate, in his opinion. Otherwise, I ask the question again.

Comment: Yes, it is true, now I have read the answer, and ... yes, they are the same! My question is covered in the answer to that question .... thanks Erik and Hackworth. And sorry!

Comment: Thank you @Erik. It is also true, however, that my question is  different from the linked one. If the answer to that question is also capable of solving my question, how can I know in advance? It is already a lot if I see similar questions already asked in SE, but how can I check all the answers immediately,too?

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin You could always try the search function. If you just type "fight trample" into the search bar, the question would have appeared as the 2nd result. If you get too many non-Magic-related results, you can narrow the search to questions with a certain tag, like so: "[magic-the-gathering] fight trample".

Comment: Yes Hackworth, it's true. But it is also true that the answer to my question is in an answer to a question different from mine; moreover it is literally in one line of that answer. Now that you've done the search it's all easier. However, if in addition to looking through the questions already asked, I have to take time to read all the answers that "may" have put to my question, I can also take a lifetime of time if I'm not lucky!

Comment: I first ask the question, and at most receive a duplication from experts like you. It's not always possible what you ask me to do. But, anyway I thank you for this: after all, you didn't realize it right away,too: you had answered my question, and very well! Then, you noticed the duplication, and you edited everything. See you next time!